# Testing Moonbeam parachain staking

Tags: parachain, staking, parachain-collator, moonbeam

I have added Moonbeam parachain staking in our code.Can anyone please provide the full step to test it. I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.moonbeam.network/tokens/staking/stake/#staking-your-tokens for testing, But I'm not getting any rewards, but all other extrinsics are doing well.
Thanks in advance!